# PYTHONPATH not propagating from CMD to Spyder

Tags: python, pyspark, cmd, anaconda, spyder

I installed PySpark under Anaconda by issuing the following commands
at a Conda prompt:

```
conda create -n py39 python=3.9 anaconda
conda activate py39
conda install openjdk
conda install pyspark
conda install -c conda-forge findspark
```

As can be seen, this is all within the `py39` environment.
Additionally, I fetched **Hadoop 2.7.1** from
[GitHub](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils) and created
`c:%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Hadoop\2.7.1` to contain the corresponding
`README.md` file and `bin` subfolder [1].  Here, `%HOMEPATH%` is
`\Users\User.Name`.  Finally, I had to create file
`%SPARK_HOME%/conf/spark-defaults.conf` (Annex A).

With the above setup, I could launch PySpark using the following
`myspark.cmd` script located in
`c:%HOMEPATH%\anaconda3\envs\py39\bin\`:

```
set "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python"
set "PYSPARK_PYTHON=python"
set "HADOOP_HOME=c:%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Hadoop\2.7.1"
pyspark
```

I am now following [this
page](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/setup-and-run-pyspark-on-spyder-ide)
to be able to use Spyder instead of the Conda command line.  I am
using the following `SpyderSpark.cmd` script to set the the variables
and launch Spyder:

```
set "HADOOP_HOME=c:%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Hadoop\2.7.1"
set "JAVA_HOME=C:%HOMEPATH%\anaconda3\envs\py39\Library"
set "SPARK_HOME=C:%HOMEPATH%\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark"
set "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=Python"
set "PYSPARK_PYTHON=Python"
set "PYTHONPATH=%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip;%PYTHONPATH%"
set "PYTHONPATH=%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python;%PYTHONPATH%"

C:%HOMEPATH%\anaconda3\pythonw.exe ^
C:%HOMEPATH%\anaconda3\cwp.py ^
C:%HOMEPATH%\anaconda3\envs\py39 ^
C:%HOMEPATH%\anaconda3\envs\py39\pythonw.exe ^
C:%HOMEPATH%\anaconda3\envs\py39\Scripts\spyder-script.py
```

Some points that may not be clear:

- Folder `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` contains `java.exe` and `javac.exe`
- The second half of the above code block is the command that is
  executed by Anaconda's shortcut for `Spyder (py39)`

As I am still trying to get `SpyderSpark.cmd` to work, I execute it
from the Conda prompt, specifically the `py39` environment.  This way,
it inherits environment variables that I may have missed in
`SpyderSpark.cmd`.  Issuing `SpyderSpark.cmd` launches the Spyder GUI,
but Spark commands aren't recognized at the console.  Here is a
transcript of the response to the the first few lines of code from
[this
tutorial](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/different-ways-to-create-dataframe-in-pyspark):

```
In [1]: columns = ["language","users_count"]
   ...: data = [("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000")]
In [2]: spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()
NameError: name 'SparkSession' is not defined
```

The likely cause is that all but the `PYTHONPATH` variable propagated
their values into the Spyder session.  From the Spyder console:

```
import os
print(os.environ.get("HADOOP_HOME"))
print(os.environ.get("JAVA_HOME"))
print(os.environ.get("SPARK_HOME"))
print(os.environ.get("PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON"))
print(os.environ.get("PYSPARK_PYTHON"))
print(os.environ.get("PYTHONPATH"))

   c:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Hadoop\2.7.1
   C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\Library
   C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark
   Python
   Python
   None
```

**Why isn't `PYTHONPATH` propagating into the Spyder session, and how
can I fix this?**

I don't think that [this
Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086454) explains the
problem because I *am* launching Spyder from a CMD environment *after*
setting the variable.  Furthermore, all the other variables succeed in
propagating to the Spyder session.

**Notes**

**[1]** Using Cygwin, I found that for all the files in
`c:%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Hadoop\2.7.1\bin`, the permission bits for
execution were disabled and needed to be explicitly enabled.

**Afternote 2023-09-02:**

Respondents posted helpful hints on how to get Spark commands
recognized in Spyder, i.e., to first issue `from pyspark.sql import SparkSession`. I didn't see this tutorial code because it was in a screen capture and the image was blocked by AdBlocker.  Also, it was not needed after issuing `pyspark` from the Conda prompt of the `py39` environment.  It was needed after issuing `SpyderSpark.cmd`, as I found from the comments, and this allowed the Spark statements to be recognized.  I assume, therefore, that `pyspark` imports `SparkSession` on the user's behalf, making it unnecessary to explicitly import it after launching `pyspark` from the Conda prompt.

As useful as it was to know that SparkSession needs to be imported from within Spyder, it doesn't answer the question of why 1 of 6
environment variables fail to propagate from `SpyderSpark.cmd` to Spyder,
i.e., variable `PYTHONPATH`.  Admittedly, it solved the real
showstopper for me at present, which is to get Spark working from Spyder, for which I thank the respondents.
I would still be interested in why `PYTHONPATH` doesn't propagate.

On a separate but related issue, I found it tricky to create a shortcut to
`SpyderSpark.cmd` that doesn't leave a redundant terminal on the
desktop.  The solution turned out to be to prefix the Spyder launching
command with [`start`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70713834/2153235):

```
set "HADOOP_HOME=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Hadoop\2.7.1"
set "JAVA_HOME=%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\py39\Library"
set "SPARK_HOME=%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark"
set "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=Python"
set "PYSPARK_PYTHON=Python"
set "PYTHONPATH=%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip;%PYTHONPATH%"
set "PYTHONPATH=%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python;%PYTHONPATH%"

start "" ^
%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\pythonw.exe ^
%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\cwp.py ^
%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\py39 ^
%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\py39\pythonw.exe ^
%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\py39\Scripts\spyder-script.py
```

All the arguments starting with `%USERPROFILE%` would ideally be
enclosed in double-quotes in case they expand to include
non-alphanumeric characters.  For some reason, I couldn't do that
without incurring the incorrect behaviour in Annex B (below).  Therefore, I did not adorn the arguments with double-quotes.

With SpyderSpark as revised above, the `Target` field of the Windows shortcut
should contain:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C "%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\py39\bin\SpyderSpark.cmd"
```

I found it handy to simply copy the Spyder shortcut and modify the
`Target` field.  For the sake of readability, here is the same command
broken into two physical lines (which isn't suitable for the `Target`
field of a shortcut):

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C ^
   "%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\py39\bin\SpyderSpark.cmd"
```

Thanks to *Mofi* for advice on having improved this afternote.

**Further troubleshooting 2023-09-03**

To further troubleshoot the propagation of environment variable `PYTHONPATH` into Spyder, I followed Mofi's advice and revised `SpyderSpark.cmd` to use the
console oriented `python` rather than GUI-oriented `pythonw`:

```
set "HADOOP_HOME=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Hadoop\2.7.1"
set "JAVA_HOME=%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\py39\Library"
set "SPARK_HOME=%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark"
set "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=Python"
set "PYSPARK_PYTHON=Python"
set "PYTHONPATH=%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip;%PYTHONPATH%"
set "PYTHONPATH=%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python;%PYTHONPATH%"

set PYTHONPATH & REM HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\python.exe ^
%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\cwp-debug.py ^
%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\py39 ^
%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\py39\python.exe ^
%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\py39\Scripts\spyder-script.py
```

As can be seen from above, `PYTHONPATH` is also displayed to the screen prior to the Spyder launching command.  Furthermore, `SpyderSpark.cmd` was revised
to use a modified `cwp.py`, dubbed `cwp-debug.py`, wherein
`PYTHONPATH` is printed out twice:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
from os.path import join, pathsep

from menuinst.knownfolders import FOLDERID, get_folder_path, PathNotFoundException

# call as: python cwp.py PREFIX ARGs...

prefix = sys.argv[1]
args = sys.argv[2:]

new_paths = pathsep.join([prefix,
                         join(prefix, "Library", "mingw-w64", "bin"),
                         join(prefix, "Library", "usr", "bin"),
                         join(prefix, "Library", "bin"),
                         join(prefix, "Scripts")])
print(os.environ["PYTHONPATH"]) ###################
env = os.environ.copy()
env['PATH'] = new_paths + pathsep + env['PATH']
env['CONDA_PREFIX'] = prefix

documents_folder, exception = get_folder_path(FOLDERID.Documents)
if exception:
    documents_folder, exception = get_folder_path(FOLDERID.PublicDocuments)
if not exception:
    os.chdir(documents_folder)
print(env["PYTHONPATH"]) ######################
sys.exit(subprocess.call(args, env=env))
```

When `SpyderSpark.cmd` is executed from a CMD console, the expected
`PYTHONPATH` is printed out by `SpyderSpark.cmd` *and* at both
locations in `cwp-debug.py`.  Furthermore, `PYTHONPATH` is echoed
to the screen when it is prepended to in `SpyderSpark.cmd`.  I have
lumped together lines in the session transcript so that the different
echoings of `PYTHONPATH` are easier to recognize:

```
C:\Users\User.Name> C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\bin\SpyderSpark.cmd

C:\Users\User.Name> set "HADOOP_HOME=C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Hadoop\2.7.1"
C:\Users\User.Name> set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\Library"
C:\Users\User.Name> set "SPARK_HOME=C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark"
C:\Users\User.Name> set "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=Python"
C:\Users\User.Name> set "PYSPARK_PYTHON=Python"
C:\Users\User.Name> set "PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip;"
C:\Users\User.Name> set "PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python;C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip;"

C:\Users\User.Name> set PYTHONPATH   & REM HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python;C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip;

C:\Users\User.Name> C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\cwp-debug.py C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39 C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\python.exe C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\Scripts\spyder-script.py

C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python;C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip;
C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python;C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip;

fromIccProfile: failed minimal tag size sanity
C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py:219: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Blowfish has been deprecated
  "class": algorithms.Blowfish,

C:\Users\User.Name>
```

The final warnings about `fromIccProfile` and `Blowfish` are
innocuous.  Explanations about the `fromIccProfile` warning can be
found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65463848) and
[here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/18026) while the
`Blowfish` warning is just about deprecation.  Therefore, the modifications to `SpyderSpark` and `cwp.py` (in the form of `cwp-debug.py`) did not reveal why `PYTHONPATH` fails to propagate to Spyder.

The next step was to check whether `PYTHONPATH` was being clobbered
by `spyder-script.py`, which is a very short script:

```
import re
import sys

from spyder.app.start import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

I'm actually trying to spin up on Python, so I'm wondering whether
anyone can help decipher this code.

**Further troubleshooting 2023-09-06**

[Mofi](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56650189#56650189)
explained that the regular expression substitution in
`spyder-script.py` above simply strips away a suffix `-script.py[w]`
or `.exe` from the script name, which merely affects the file identification
shown in diagnostic messages.

I noticed that the ensuing statement invokes `main()` from module
`spyder.app.start`.  I examined
`%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\py39\Lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py`,
with emphasis on `main()`.  I found pre-amble code that removes `PYTHONPATH`
paths from `sys.path`.  I confirmed this from within Spyder: `sys.path`
contains neither of the PySpark paths that are added to `PYTHONPATH` by
`SpyderSpark.cmd`.  `PYTHONPATH` is empty before running
`SpyderSpark.cmd`, so there are no other paths to check.

As for the disappearance of `PYTHONPATH` itself, I could see no code in
`start.py` that modifies `os.environ['PYTHONPATH']` or removes that
variable from the environment.  However, it doesn't really matter,
as `PYTHONPATH` merely contributes to `sys.path` and `start.py`
explicitly removes `PYTHONPATH` paths from `sys.path`.

I lack the experience to appreciate why this is done. Spyder is supposed to provide a development IDE, but it's hard to use if it removes the paths in PYTHONPATH.

## Annex A: %SPARK_HOME%/conf/spark-defaults.conf

Here, `%SPARK_HOME%` is
`C:%HOMEPATH%\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark`:

```
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.eventLog.dir C:\\Users\\User.Name\\anaconda3\\envs\\py39\\PySparkLogs
spark.history.fs.logDirectory C:\\Users\\User.Name\\anaconda3\\envs\\py39\\PySparkLogs
spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold -1
```

## Annex B: Incorrect behaviour when `start` arguments are double-quoted in `SpyderSpark.cmd`

When `SpyderSpark.cmd` is run, a terminal console appears with the following
messages:

```
C:\Users\User.Name\Documents\Python Scripts>set "HADOOP_HOME=C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Hadoop\2.7.1"
C:\Users\User.Name\Documents\Python Scripts>set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\Library"
C:\Users\User.Name\Documents\Python Scripts>set "SPARK_HOME=C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark"
C:\Users\User.Name\Documents\Python Scripts>set "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=Python"
C:\Users\User.Name\Documents\Python Scripts>set "PYSPARK_PYTHON=Python"
C:\Users\User.Name\Documents\Python Scripts>set "PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip;"
C:\Users\User.Name\Documents\Python Scripts>set "PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python;C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip;"
C:\Users\User.Name\Documents\Python Scripts>start "" "C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\pythonw.exe" ^
C:\Users\User.Name\Documents\Python Scripts>"C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\cwp.py" "C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39" ^
[main 2023-09-02T23:29:02.117Z] update#setState idle
[main 2023-09-02T23:29:04.434Z] WSL is not installed, so could not detect WSL profiles
```

The VS Code app then appears, opened to a file `cwp.py` (the 2nd
argument supplied to `start`in `SpyderSpark.cmd`).  When I exit VS Code, the following
additional messages are printed to the terminal console, followed by
the appearance of the Spyder app:

```
[main 2023-09-02T23:29:09.998Z] Extension host with pid 21404 exited with code: 0, signal: unknown.
C:\Users\User.Name\Documents\Python Scripts>"C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\pythonw.exe" "C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\Scripts\spyder-script.py"
```

When I exit Spyder, the terminal console then disappears.

**2023-09-06 afternote:** According to [Mofi](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56640702#56640702), the cause for all of this unexpected behaviour is incorrect parsing of the Spyder launching command as a multi-line statement.  Specifically, the caret symbol at the end of a physical line indicates the continuation of the statement on the next line, and this caret should *not* be preceded by a space.  Rather, the next physical line, which the statement continues onto, should *start* with a space.  With this fix, arguments to `Start` can be double=quoted and the script still launches Spyder in the expected manner.  Here is the revised and properly working `SpyderSpark.cmd`:

```
set "HADOOP_HOME=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Hadoop\2.7.1"
set "JAVA_HOME=%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\py39\Library"
set "SPARK_HOME=%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark"
set "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=Python"
set "PYSPARK_PYTHON=Python"
set "PYTHONPATH=%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip;%PYTHONPATH%"
set "PYTHONPATH=%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python;%PYTHONPATH%"

start ""^
 "%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\pythonw.exe"^
 "%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\cwp.py"^
 "%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\py39"^
 "%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\py39\pythonw.exe"^
 "%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\py39\Scripts\spyder-script.py"
```

Other than for aesthetics, I have not seen described anywhere this prescription to avoid a space before the caret and to start the next line with a space.  However, it works.  In this specific case, the need to start a continuation line with a space could be due to the fact that the first character is `"`, which is meant to delimit a file path but is not part of the file path.  Since the first character of a continuation line is [automatically escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21000752/2153235), we do not want the `"` to be the first character or else it loses its special meaning.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255155/discussion-on-question-by-user2153235-pythonpath-not-propagating-from-cmd-to-spy); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in section *Further troubleshooting 2023-09-06* in the
question, `start.py` removes `PYTHONPATH` paths from `sys.path`.  With
a bit more test driving of Spyder, one possible reason became clear:
Spyder maintains it's *own* `PYTHONPATH` as a tool parameter (Tools ->
PYTHONPATH manager`).

[This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108285) shows how to
add to `sys.path` the paths from the `PYTHONPATH` of the shell that executed Spyder, ideally testing for their presence beforehand.
One could write a script to do this and specify the script's full path via Spyder's `Tools -> Preferences -> IPython console -> Startup (tab)`.

It's not clear to me *why* Spyder was designed to maintain its own
`PYTHONPATH` rather than inheritting it from the environment.
`PYTHONPATH` depends on how other Python packages/modules are set up,
which changes piece-wise with time.  It's hazardous to manage
manually.

It is interesting to see that in 2019, Spyder did inherit `PYTHONPATH`
from the environment *if* `Tools -> Preferences -> Python interpreter -> Python interpreter` was set to `Default (i.e. the same as Spyder's)` (see [this GitHub bug
ticket](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/8681)).  In this
bug ticket, it was going to be fixed imminently, so it seems that the
fix was to use the `PYTHONPATH` from Spyder's *PYTHONPATH manager* in
all cases.

Just as a test, however, I set `Python interpreter` to
`C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\python.exe`, which was the
path shown by issuing `where python` from Conda prompt of the *py39*
environment.  After both of the following tests, nothing was still
shown from `import os; os.environ.get("PYTHONPATH")`:

- `exit()` from the Spyder console, which I guess restarts the python interpreter
- Exiting and restarting Spyder

Also relevant from 2019 is [this
request](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/pull/8685) "Avoid
dropping predefined PYTHONPATH when using an external interpreter".
I'm not familiar enough with GitHub to follow what happened to this
request, so if anyone can weigh in, thanks!

Finally, I also found that **unless you put custom paths into
`PYTHONPATH`, it doesn't need to propagate into Spyder.**

In the posted question, the two paths added to `PYTHONPATH` are from
issuing `os.environ.get("PYTHONPATH")` after launching `pyspark` from
within `myspark.cmd`.  Even though `PYTHONPATH` was empty within Spyder,
I found that the two paths are included in `sys.path`, directly or
indirectly.

The first of the two `PYTHONPATH` paths is
`%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip`.  If I try to add this
to Spyder's PYTHONPATH manager, it complains that the path is invalid.
Examining the files therein and using Cygwin's `find` on folder
`%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs/py39` reveals that the files are
unpacked into package folder
`%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\py39\Lib\site-packages\py4j`.  If I
correctly understand my readings about packages, package `py4j` is
available to Python because `sys.cmd` already includes
`%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages`.  Why
`PYTHONPATH` pointed to the zip file from within a `pyspark` session,
I do not know.

The second `PYTHONPATH` path is `%SPARK_HOME%\python`.  This is
already included in `sys.path` within Spyder.

A question that remained was whether Spyder startup scripts figured
out to add these two paths to `sys.path` because `SpyderSpark.cmd`
added them to `PYTHONPATH` beforehand.  I removed the setting of
`PYTHONPATH` from `SpyderSpark.cmd` and sure enough, the two paths were
still present in `sys.path` within Spyder.

It seems, therefore, that the scripts responsible for launching Spyder also add the
necessary paths to `sys.path` without the need for `PYTHONPATH`.  I
suspect that this is because Conda sets up the environment with all
the necessary dependencies.

I also confirmed that if `PYTHONPATH` did contain custom paths prior
to launching Spyder, they did not propagate to `sys.path` within
Spyder.  This simply corroborates with the fact that the *py4j* zip
file pointed to by `PYTHONPATH` also didn't propagate into `sys.path`.
I presume, therefore, that one would need to use Spyder's PYTHONPATH manager for
custom paths or add the custom paths to `sys.path` using code.

Answer (score 1):

there might be a few issues that need to be addressed:

1 - Environment Variable Formatting:
In your code, you're using %HOMEPATH% without surrounding it with % signs. It should be %HOMEPATH% to properly reference the home directory. For example, instead of `c:%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Hadoop\2.7.1`, it should be `c:\%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Hadoop\2.7.1`.

2- Setting Environment Variables:
It's better to set the environment variables before launching PySpark to ensure that they are correctly configured for the PySpark session. In your example, you're setting the variables after running pyspark.

3- Importing SparkSession:
The error you encountered (NameError: name 'SparkSession' is not defined) indicates that you haven't imported the necessary modules for Spark. You need to import SparkSession from the pyspark.sql module at the beginning of your script.

```
# Create and activate the Conda environment
conda create -n py39 python=3.9 anaconda
conda activate py39

# Install necessary packages
conda install openjdk
conda install pyspark

# Set environment variables (adjust paths accordingly)
set "HADOOP_HOME=C:\%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Hadoop\2.7.1"
set "JAVA_HOME=C:\%HOMEPATH%\anaconda3\envs\py39\Library"
set "SPARK_HOME=C:\%HOMEPATH%\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark"
set "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python"
set "PYSPARK_PYTHON=python"
set "PYTHONPATH=%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip;%PYTHONPATH%"
set "PYTHONPATH=%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\python;%PYTHONPATH%"

# Launch PySpark
pyspark
```

```
# Inside the PySpark session
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

columns = ["language", "users_count"]
data = [("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000")]

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()

# Your Spark code here
# For example, you can create a DataFrame from the data
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
df.show()

# Don't forget to stop the SparkSession when done
spark.stop()
```

After correcting the issues and following these steps, you should be able to properly launch a PySpark session within your Conda environment and interact with Spark components.

Comment: The prose around item #1 makes no sense. You say they left off `%` signs when they did not, then silently add a `\ ` (that may or may not be correct) instead of changing anything related to `%` symbols.

Comment: @residentcode: Thank you for your explanation.  I'll respond to your enumerated points: (1) This may be an error. I enclose all references to environment variables with `%`. (2) Script `myspark.cmd` does set environment variables before `pyspark`. The problem is that `pyspark` isn't invoked in `SpyderSpark.cmd`. (3) You are right. My browser did not show the screen shot in the tutorial.  I only saw the caption "PySpark application running on Spyder IDE"...

Comment: ...so I started entering code from [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/different-ways-to-create-dataframe-in-pyspark).  I could see the screen shot after switching browsers, and the `import` command did indeed make Spark commands recognizable. However, that is just the context for the question, albeit very important. The question is why 1 of 6 variables do not propagate into Spyder.  Would you be able to comment on that?

Comment: The directory path assigned to the environment variable `HOMEPATH` begins always with a backslash. There should not be used `c:\%HOMEPATH%` as that results finally after environment variable expansion in `c:\\Users\User.Name` which the Windows file IO functions must later automatically correct most likely multiple times to `c:\Users\User.Name`. It would be better to use `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` instead of `C:\%HOMEPATH%` or much better `%USERPROFILE%` and `%LOCALAPPDATA%` instead of `C:\%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local` in the batch script.