# Perusing Python help() details and getting them in Spyder's Help pane

Tags: python, spyder

I have Spyder running with Spark as per the details in [this posted
question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77019827) (Annex A and
`SpyderSpark.cmd` in Annex B).  Before accessing Spark
classes, methods, objects, and help, I first had to import the module and
create the top-level object:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
       .appName("SparkExamples.com").getOrCreate()
```

With Spark set up, when I enter `spark` into Spyder's
Help pane, I get a very short description:

```
The entry point to programming Spark with the Dataset and
DataFrame API.

A SparkSession can be used to create DataFrame, register DataFrame
as tables, execute SQL over tables, cache tables, and read parquet
files. To create a SparkSession, use the following builder
pattern:

Changed in version 3.4.0: Supports Spark Connect.

Examples
Create a Spark session.

>>> spark = (
...     SparkSession.builder
...         .master("local")
...         .appName("Word Count")
...         .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
...         .getOrCreate()
... )

Create a Spark session with Spark Connect.

>>> spark = (
...     SparkSession.builder
...         .remote("sc://localhost")
...         .appName("Word Count")
...         .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
...         .getOrCreate()
... )
```

In contrast, if I issue `help(spark)` in the console pane, I get much
more information -- more than can fit into the cached console lines,
even if I pan to the top.

1. How can I enable a pager for the more detailed help so that I can
   see more than just the bottom-most text for which the console buffer
   has room for?
2. How can I get the more detailed help in the Spyder Help pane?
   Perhaps it will allow one to view the entire help text.

**Afternote:**  Aside from the inability to
peruse the entirety of the detailed help,
I found other oddities in using the Spyder Help pane.  For example,
If I enter `SparkSesssion`, the Help pane explains this as:

```
Definition : SparkSession(...)

Type : Function of pyspark.sql.session module
```

However, it isn't a function, but rather, a class.  I'm wondering how
much I have to take the wording of the Help pane with a grain of salt.
Subtleties like that determine how I go about searching for further
details and can cause unintended detours for newbies (among which I
count myself).

**This is potentially an old problem:** iPython's general lack of a pager seems to go back [many years](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/7311)

**Work-around** Using `pandas.DataFrame` as an example, if you imported `pandas` as `pd`, then issuing `pd.DataFrame?` at the console gives the same short help as in the Help pane, but it additionally provides the source file path.  You can then delve into the file to peruse the class definition, methods, properties, attributes, etc.

Yes, it seems odd to have to locate and read source files to understand how to use classes and methods.  After all, OOP is about encapsulation, detail hiding, and separating interface from implementation.  However, one can just focus on the doc strings and the function prototypes to see the interface aspects of a class, similar to what one would see in user level documentation.

Comment: @TheClockTwister: I see that you added extra tags pertaining to Spark. This question really wasn't meant to focus on Spark, but rather, on understanding how to use `help()` and the Help pane within Spyder.  Am I missing something?